# How can you see what is commit from git is currently deployed with Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

With Capistrano, how can you see what version of your source code is in the current release? I.e. how do you see which git commit was most recently deployed?

Answer (score 0):

There is a file called REVISION in the release folder, just look into it.

more info: https://makandracards.com/makandra/10105-capistrano-how-to-find-out-which-version-of-your-application-is-currently-live

Comment: Is there a command to do this without having to ssh into the server?

Comment: Try invoke: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Capistrano-Tasks#invoke i.e. `cap ROLES=app COMMAND="cat REVISION" invoke`